# eBay Trading API AddItem issues in Germany SiteID

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have PHP SDK for Trading API. I used the sandbox account with US `SiteID`, it's working fine, but I tried with Germany `SiteID` like DE, it's not working. Does anyone have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

The error I get is like this (translated to English)

> "Error : Invalid input data . Input data for day Original text are
>   invalid or missing . Contribute a better translationare invalid or
>   missing . Please read the API documentation "

Original in German:

> "Error: Ungültige Eingabedaten. Eingabedaten für Tag sind ungültig
>   oder fehlen. Bitte lesen Sie die API-Dokumentation."

Comment: Can you write you entire request which you are sending in eBay ?